# SERVER -> CLIENT: 452 4.5.3 Error: too many recipients

Tags: php, email, client-server, phpmailer, contact-form

Dear Goblin Slayers (Developers), I have been trying to solve this issue for two days.. I am trying to build a mailer for marketing purposes to a company based on PHP mailer, My code worked fine when we sent an HTML file to 6-8(more or less) recipients but when we tried to send the HTML file to more then one hundred recipients via my localhost, I get the following error:

```
2021-03-12 14:10:30 SMTP INBOUND: "452 4.5.3 Error: too many recipients"
2021-03-12 14:10:30 SERVER -> CLIENT: 452 4.5.3 Error: too many recipients
```

My Code is the following :

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once 'folder/dbh.inc.php';
include 'folder/index.inc.php';

$content = file_get_contents('body_file.html');

// An array that contains the List of recipients

$emailst = array("100-500 recipients");

$emailst_length = count($emailst) - 1;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


//Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    
    require 'folder/credentials.inc.php';


    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('emailOfTheCompany.com', 'company name');
    $mail->addAddress('another email of the company', 'company name');
    
    for ($i=0; $i <= $emailst_length; $i++) { 
        $mail->addBCC($emailst[$i]);
    }

//Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->Subject = 'Welcome To Subject';
    $mail->Body    = $content;
    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is returned to the sender to indicate that a distribution list is too big. The reason these limits are set is to protect against users sending spam e-mails. If you have too many names on a list, your e-mail may be marked as spam and treated as such.

The easiest way to prevent this error is to create distribution lists with a reasonable amount of e-mail addresses. Less than 25 recipients if possible, although your server may allow between 50 - 75 recipients on each list.

You can find out the limits for sending e-mails by checking the SMTP server documentation or your ISP.

Comment: Thank you, I consider your comment.

Comment: I think I should now work around the problem and find a way to minimize the list of recipients to 25 recipients on each sending operation until every receiver on our database receive the email in order to convince the server that our list is not too big.. Maybe a conditional loop will work fine

Comment: Exactly! Good idea. Do not hesitate to accept my answer if it helped.